# Time Between successive DNS queries.

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking

Using a PC running Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm testing web browsing using a very low speed and low data rate link.
My system is congested with DNS queries (and other types of packets like TCP re-transmission).
How can I increase the time between each two successive DNS queries to give enough time until the response of the current query is achieved?

Is this possible? or are their other methods to solve such a problem for low speed interfaces?

Comment: Use lynk... The DNS answer is cached if successful. Want to make it work to prevent retransmission ? As packet loss is not normal, even on a 33.6 phone line, that show line problem.

Answer (score 1):

DNS congestion is pretty damn unlikely. Not only has it been around since the days of dial-up (read: serial port speeds), the `/etc/resolv.conf` defaults use a five second timeout cycle by default. There are a few knobs you can play with, but this is unlikely to be a real problem.

- Tune `timeout` and similar options in `/etc/resolv.conf`. (see `man resolv.conf`)
- Enable nscd caching of hosts in `/etc/nscd.conf` (`enable-cache hosts yes`)

If you wish to get rid of *spurious* DNS queries, you should reduce the number of domains in the `search` list and consider disabling IPv6 altogether. Even if you don't have internet routed IPv6 addresses assigned to your interfaces, the resolver library will attempt to perform `AAAA` lookups during DNS resolution and cycle through `search` domain processing whenever those lookups return `NXDOMAIN`.